# How to count data that have same value from firebase and show the number in the table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
window.onload = initializer;
var formjgrrb7;
var refValidation;
var tbodyModelJgrrb7;
var CREATE = "Temporary Validation";
var UPDATE = "Update";
var modo = CREATE;
var refValidationEditor

function initializer() {
  formjgrrb7 = document.getElementById("form-model-jgrrb7");
  formjgrrb7.addEventListener("submit",sendToValidationFirebase,false);

  refValidation = firebase.database().ref().child("Jaguarrb7");

  tbodyModelJgrrb7 =document.getElementById("tbody-model-jgrrb7");

  showDataValidationOnFirebase();
}

function showDataValidationOnFirebase(){
  refValidation.on("value",function(snap){
    var data = snap.val();
    var fileToShow = ""
    for(var key in data){
      if(data[key].status=="STANDBY"){
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#AED6F1">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="RUN")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#58D68D">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="REPAIR")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#E74C3C">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="ON-HOLD")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#F1C40F">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="WFA")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#E5E7E9">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }

    }
    tbodyModelJgrrb7.innerHTML = fileToShow;
    if(fileToShow!=""){
      var elementsEditables = document.getElementsByClassName("editor");
      for(var i = 0; i < elementsEditables.length; i++){
        elementsEditables[i].addEventListener("click",editorValidDataFirebase,false);
      }
      var elementsDelete = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
      for(var i = 0; i < elementsDelete.length; i++){
        elementsDelete[i].addEventListener("click",deleteValidDataFirebase,false);
      }
    }
  });

}

function editorValidDataFirebase(){
  var keyValidationEditor = this.getAttribute("data-validation");
  refValidationEditor = refValidation.child(keyValidationEditor);
  refValidationEditor.once("value",function(snap){
    var data = snap.val();
    document.getElementById("cavity").value= data.cavity;
    document.getElementById("status").value = data.status;
    document.getElementById("machine").value= data.machine;
    document.getElementById("rack").value= data.rack;
  });
  document.getElementById("button-tosend-validation").value = UPDATE;
  modo = UPDATE;
}

function deleteValidDataFirebase(){
  var keyValidationDelete = this.getAttribute("data-validation");
  var refValidationDelete = refValidation.child(keyValidationDelete);
  refValidationDelete.remove();
}

function sendToValidationFirebase(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  switch(modo){
    case CREATE:
    refValidation.push({
      cavity:event.target.cavity.value,
      status:event.target.status.value,
      machine:event.target.machine.value,
      rack:event.target.rack.value
    });
    break;
    case UPDATE:
    refValidationEditor.update({
      cavity:event.target.cavity.value,
      status:event.target.status.value,
      machine:event.target.machine.value,
      rack:event.target.rack.value
    });
    break;
  }

  formjgrrb7.reset();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mould Status</title>
<style>
#container{
  width: 100%;
}
  header,footer{
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #5D645F;
  }
  nav{
    background-color: #5D645F;

  }
  #button1{
    background-color:#5D645F;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding:15px 32px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #button1:hover{background-color: #06C53C;}
  #button-tosend-validation{
  background-color: #5D645F;
  color: white;
  width:150px;
  height:40px
  }
  #button-tosend-validation:hover{background-color: #06C53C;}

  #trdisplay{
    background-color: teal;
    color: white;
  }
  #tbdisplay{
    text-align: center;
  }
  #thdisplay{
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.9/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyADGLd5Uv9MNdu0b7eemTfyJhAsAG0hbNA",
    authDomain: "mould-ae9c8.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mould-ae9c8.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "mould-ae9c8.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "309171185250"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="js/jaguarrb7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
    <thead>
      <header>
        <h2>JAGUAR RB7</h2>
      </header>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="text-align:center;width:100%">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html" id="button1">HOME</a>
        <a href="jaguarrb7.html" id="button1" style="float:right">JAGUAR-RB7</a>
        <a href="jaguar2b.html" id="button1" style="float:right">JAGUAR-2B</a>
        <a href="firebolt6.html" id="button1" style="float:right">FIREBOLT-6</a>
        <a href="palmar.html" id="button1" style="float:right">PALMAR</a>
        <a href="cobraf3d.html" id="button1" style="float:right">COBRA-F-3D</a>
        <a href="cobraf2d.html" id="button1" style="float:right">COBRA-F-2D</a>
        <a href="kingcobra.html" id="button1" style="float:right">KINGCOBRA</a>
        <a href="14se.html" id="button1" style="float:right">14SE</a>
  </nav>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-2">
          <form id="form-model-jgrrb7">
            <div class="form-group">
              <br><br>
              <label for="cavity">Cavity</label><br>
              <select  name="Acavity" id="cavity"  class ="form-control" style="width:150px">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="#1">#1</option>
                <option value="#2">#2</option>
                <option value="#3">#3</option>
                <option value="#4">#4</option>
                <option value="#5">#5</option>
                <option value="#6">#6</option>
                <option value="#7">#7</option>
                <option value="#8">#8</option>
                <option value="#9">#9</option>
                <option value="#10">#10</option>
                <option value="#11">#11</option>
                <option value="#12">#12</option>
                <option value="#13">#13</option>
                <option value="#14">#14</option>
                <option value="#15">#15</option>
                <option value="#16">#16</option>
                <option value="#17">#17</option>
                <option value="#18">#18</option>
                <option value="#19">#19</option>
                <option value="#20">#20</option>
                <option value="#21">#21</option>
                <option value="#22">#22</option>
                <option value="#23">#23</option>
                <option value="#24">#24</option>
                <option value="#25">#25</option>
                <option value="#26">#26</option>
                <option value="#27">#27</option>
                <option value="#28">#28</option>
                <option value="#29">#29</option>
                <option value="#30">#30</option>
                <option value="#31">#31</option>
                <option value="#32">#32</option>
                <option value="#33">#33</option>
                <option value="#34">#34</option>
                <option value="#35">#35</option>
                <option value="#36">#36</option>
                <option value="#37">#37</option>
                <option value="#38">#38</option>
                <option value="#39">#39</option>
                <option value="#40">#40</option>
                <option value="#41">#41</option>
                <option value="#42">#42</option>
                <option value="#43">#43</option>
                <option value="#44">#44</option>
                <option value="#45">#45</option>
                <option value="#46">#46</option>
                <option value="#47">#47</option>
                <option value="#48">#48</option>
                <option value="#49">#49</option>
                <option value="#50">#50</option>
                <option value="#51">#51</option>
                <option value="#52">#52</option>
                <option value="#53">#53</option>
                <option value="#54">#54</option>
                <option value="#55">#55</option>
                <option value="#56">#56</option>
                <option value="#57">#57</option>
                <option value="#58">#58</option>
                <option value="#59">#59</option>
                <option value="#60">#60</option>
                <option value="#61">#61</option>
                <option value="#62">#62</option>
                <option value="#63">#63</option>
                <option value="#64">#64</option>
                <option value="#65">#65</option>
                <option value="#66">#66</option>
                <option value="#67">#67</option>
                <option value="#68">#68</option>
                <option value="#69">#69</option>
                <option value="#70">#70</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="status">Status</label><br>
              <select style="width:150px" class ="form-control" name="Astatus" id="status">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="STANDBY">STANDBY</option>
                  <option value="WFA">WFA</option>
                  <option value="RUN">RUN</option>
                  <option value="REPAIR">REPAIR</option>
                  <option value="ON-HOLD">ON-HOLD</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="machine">Machine</label><br>
              <select style="width:150px" class ="form-control" name="Amachine" id="machine">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="M1">M1</option>
                <option value="M2">M2</option>
                <option value="M3">M3</option>
                <option value="M4">M4</option>
                <option value="M5">M5</option>
                <option value="M6">M6</option>
                <option value="M7">M7</option>
                <option value="M8">M8</option>
                <option value="M9">M9</option>
                <option value="M10">M10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="rack">Rack</label><br>
              <select style="width:150px" class ="form-control" name="Arack" id="rack" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
                <option value="E">E</option>
                <option value="F">F</option>
                <option value="G">G</option>
                <option value="H">H</option>
                <option value="I">I</option>
                <option value="J">J</option>
                <option value="K">K</option>
                <option value="L">L</option>
                <option value="M">M</option>
                <option value="N">N</option>
                <option value="O">O</option>
                <option value="P">P</option>
                <option value="Q">Q</option>
                <option value="R">R</option>
                <option value="S">S</option>
                <option value="T">T</option>
                <option value="U">U</option>
                <option value="V">V</option>
                <option value="W">W</option>
                <option value="X">X</option>
                <option value="Y">Y</option>
                <option value="Z">Z</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input style="" type="submit" name=""  value="OK" id="button-tosend-validation">
          </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <br><br>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:#AED6F1;width:100px;text-align:center">STANDBY</td>
          <td id="status-jgrrrb7-standby"><td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:#58D68D;100px;text-align:center">RUN</td>
          <td id="status-jgrrb7-run"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:#E74C3C;100px;text-align:center">REPAIR</td>
          <td id="status-jgrrb7-repair"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:#F1C40F;100px;text-align:center">ON-HOLD</td>
          <td id="status-jgrrb7-onhold"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:#E5E7E9;100px;text-align:center">WFA</td>
          <td id="status-jgrrb7-wfa"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <br><br>
      <table class="table table-hover" id="tbdisplay">
        <thead>
          <tr id="trdisplay">
            <th id="thdisplay">Cavity</th>
            <th id="thdisplay">Status</th>
            <th id="thdisplay">Machine</th>
            <th id="thdisplay">Rack</th>
            <th id="thdisplay">Edit</th>
            <th id="thdisplay">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody-model-jgrrb7">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a newbie with firebase. In my HTML program I can add, edit, delete and show the data on the table display. I want to count value status `"STANDBY","RUN","REPAIR","ON-HLD","WFA"` and display it on status table. How do I count and display the number of statuses?

[image: screenshot of the program]

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is no simple count function. You have to manually count the children.

Comment: how to manually count the children? please help me with detail coding

Comment: what does your code look like so far

Comment: Hitscotty, my code at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using this code:

```js
function showStatus(){
  var index = $("table thead th:contains('Status')").index()+1;
  var cells = $("table tbody td:nth-child("+index+")");

  var standbyCount = cells.filter(":contains('STANDBY')").length;
  var runCount = cells.filter(":contains('RUN')").length;
  var repairCount = cells.filter(":contains('REPAIR')").length;
  var onholdCount = cells.filter(":contains('ON-HOLD')").length;
  var wfaCount = cells.filter(":contains('WFA')").length;

  $('#statusjgrrb7standby').html(standbyCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7run').html(runCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7repair').html(repairCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7onhold').html(onholdCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7wfa').html(wfaCount);
}
```

so the full script look like this:

```js
window.onload = initializer;
var formjgrrb7;
var refValidation;
var tbodyModelJgrrb7;
var CREATE = "Temporary Validation";
var UPDATE = "Update";
var modo = CREATE;
var refValidationEditor

function initializer() {
  formjgrrb7 = document.getElementById("form-model-jgrrb7");
  formjgrrb7.addEventListener("submit",sendToValidationFirebase,false);
  refValidation = firebase.database().ref().child("Jaguarrb7");
  tbodyModelJgrrb7 =document.getElementById("tbody-model-jgrrb7");

  showDataValidationOnFirebase();
}
function showDataValidationOnFirebase(){
  refValidation.on("value",function(snap){
    var data = snap.val();
    var fileToShow = ""
    for(var key in data){
      if(data[key].status=="STANDBY"){
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#AED6F1">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="RUN")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#58D68D">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="REPAIR")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#E74C3C">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="ON-HOLD")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#F1C40F">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
      if(data[key].status=="WFA")
      {
        fileToShow += "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].cavity +"</td>" +
                      '<td style="background-color:#E5E7E9">' + data[key].status +'</td>' +
                      "<td>" + data[key].machine +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" + data[key].rack +"</td>" +
                      "<td>" +
                      '<button class="btn btn-default editor" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      "</td>" +
                      '<td>'+
                      '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-validation = "'+ key +'">' +
                      '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
                      '</button>' +
                      '</td>' +
                      "</tr>";
      }
    }
    tbodyModelJgrrb7.innerHTML = fileToShow;
    showStatus();
    if(fileToShow!=""){
      var elementsEditables = document.getElementsByClassName("editor");
      for(var i = 0; i < elementsEditables.length; i++){
        elementsEditables[i].addEventListener("click",editorValidDataFirebase,false);
      }
      var elementsDelete = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
      for(var i = 0; i < elementsDelete.length; i++){
        elementsDelete[i].addEventListener("click",deleteValidDataFirebase,false);
      }
    }
  });
}

function editorValidDataFirebase(){
  var keyValidationEditor = this.getAttribute("data-validation");
  refValidationEditor = refValidation.child(keyValidationEditor);
  refValidationEditor.once("value",function(snap){
    var data = snap.val();
    document.getElementById("cavity").value= data.cavity;
    document.getElementById("status").value = data.status;
    document.getElementById("machine").value= data.machine;
    document.getElementById("rack").value= data.rack;
  });
  document.getElementById("button-tosend-validation").value = UPDATE;
  modo = UPDATE;
}

function deleteValidDataFirebase(){
  var keyValidationDelete = this.getAttribute("data-validation");
  var refValidationDelete = refValidation.child(keyValidationDelete);
  refValidationDelete.remove();
}

function sendToValidationFirebase(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  switch(modo){
    case CREATE:
    refValidation.push({
      cavity:event.target.cavity.value,
      status:event.target.status.value,
      machine:event.target.machine.value,
      rack:event.target.rack.value
    });
    break;
    case UPDATE:
    refValidationEditor.update({
      cavity:event.target.cavity.value,
      status:event.target.status.value,
      machine:event.target.machine.value,
      rack:event.target.rack.value
    });
    break;
  }
  formjgrrb7.reset();
}

function showStatus(){
  var index = $("table thead th:contains('Status')").index()+1;
  var cells = $("table tbody td:nth-child("+index+")");

  var standbyCount = cells.filter(":contains('STANDBY')").length;
  var runCount = cells.filter(":contains('RUN')").length;
  var repairCount = cells.filter(":contains('REPAIR')").length;
  var onholdCount = cells.filter(":contains('ON-HOLD')").length;
  var wfaCount = cells.filter(":contains('WFA')").length;

  $('#statusjgrrb7standby').html(standbyCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7run').html(runCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7repair').html(repairCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7onhold').html(onholdCount);
  $('#statusjgrrb7wfa').html(wfaCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to count the number of status you could try this, use a utility function that returns an object with the data you would need then you can access each status count easily:

```
// returns an object with all possible values and how many times they occur in data
function countStatus(data) {
  // get all the keys
  let keys = Object.keys(data);
  // get all the values at the keys into an array
  let statuses = keys.map(key => data[key]);
  // utility function to count occurrences
  let count = value => status.filter(status => status == value).length;
  // remove all duplicates and count each occurrence 
  let distinctStatuses = [...new Set(statuses)];

  // create an object of {value: count} pairs 
  return distinctStatuses.reduce((acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, {
    [key]: length(key)
  }), {});
}
```

Use would look like this:

```
let statusCounts = countStatus(data);

let standByCount = statusCounts.STANDBY;
let runCount = statusCounts.RUN;
let repairCount = statusCounts.REPAIR;
let onHoldCount = statusCounts["ON-HOLD"];
let wfaCount = statusCounts.WFA;
```

if you're strictly using only `STANDBY` ,`RUN`, `REPAIR`, `ON-HOLD`, and `WFA` a less general alternative is:

```
// returns count of a status 
function searchStatusAndCount(status, data) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]).filter(statuses => statuses == status).length;
}
```